# Text field is added when calling dialog-function of datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to get jQuery UI Datepicker thingy work on my page, and its going fine, except for one little thing: It automatically adds an input field when calling the dialog method.

This is my code

```
$('.select_date').each(function(i) {
   var input_name = $(this).attr('data-input');
   $('#'+input_name).datepicker();

   $(this).click(function() {
      var position = $(this).offset();

      $('#'+input_name).datepicker('dialog', "10/12/2012", function(date, inst) { 
           $('#'+input_name).val(date); 
         }, 
         {}, 
         [position.left + $(this).width() + 5, position.top]
      );
   });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate through the button elements with the class .select_date and for each of those elements (one on the page in question) it should bind datepicker to a hidden field with the id of the data-input attribute of the current button.

And then I'm making sure, that when I click the button, the dialog opens, and when I pick a date in the calendar, the value gets transfered to the hidden field.

All of this actually works really well, but for some reason, when clicking the button for the first time, there's added this field to the DOM:

```
<input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 265px; width: 0px; left: 674.5px;" id="dp1354917526755">
```

The funny thing is, that the position of the input field is excactly the same as for the datepicker, except that there's added 10px to the left position.